# Nonblocking data validation before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i want to validate data before saving in my rails app.
If data do not meet criteria of validation then was'nt save and the user wasn't warned.

Actually i have this in the concerned model file :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :content
    before_validation :strip_whitespace  
    private
        def strip_whitespace
            self.label = self.label.strip
            self.price = self.price.strip
        end
end
```

I have tried something like this in my other model :

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

**[EDIT]**

I finally change this line to :

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :reject_if =>  proc {|attributes| 
        attributes['label'].blank?
        attributes['price'].blank?
        attributes['img_src'].blank?
        attributes['link'].blank?
    }
end
```

And it work !
But there are another solution to list attributes with **blank?** condition ?

Comment: Try to run code from console and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having any validation in your model.
Go through this link

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: Grats for the link but i create data for this model in a form with 'fields_for' and i just want to validate data before saving, if they doesn't match with criteria the data wasn't save but without error message